# recursive exponentiator output and complexity

Tags: python-3.x

```
def exp3(a,b):
        if b == 1:
            return a
        if (b%2)*2 == b:
            return exp3(a*a, b/2)
        else: return a*exp3(a,b-1)
```

This is a recursive exponentiator program.

> Question 1:

If b is even, it will exceute (b%2)*2 == b. If b is odd, it will exceute a*exp3(a,b-1). There is no problem in my program. If b is 4, (4%2)*2=0, and 0 is not equal to b. So I can't understand how to calculate b when it's even.

> Question 2:

I want to calucate the number of steps in the program. so according to my textbook, I can get the formual as follows.
b even t(b) = 6 + t(b/2)
b odd t(b) = 6 + t(b-1)
Why is the first number 6? How can I get the number 3 in the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(b%2)*2 == b` test is never true. I think you want `b % 2 == 0` to test if `b` is even. The code still gets the right answer because the other recursive case (intended only for odd `b` values) works for even ones too (it's just less efficient).

As for your other question, I have no idea where the 6 is coming from either. It depends a lot on what you're counting as a "step". Usually it's most useful to discuss performance in terms of "Big-O" values rather than specific numbers.